# How to iterate this switchcase?

Tags: python, loops, object

I tried to create this switcher in python:

```
def mainswitcher(i):
        switcher={
                #SelfOptions#
                "test":              "SomeStringherefortest",
                "test2":          "SomeStringherefortest2",
                "test3":           "SomeStringherefortest3" }
```

Now I have to get a list of the names. So I need `list = [test,test2,test3]`

How does this work? Does it even work? I know I cant loop though an object - but is there a way around?

Comment: Like `tests = list(switcher)` ?

Comment: @khelwood How should I call this - without having i?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your switcher is a dictionary. It has keys and their values.

To get a list of the keys, simply call `switcher.keys()`.

Also, you can actually loop through most objects that have structered elements (implement Iterable).
For dictionaries, you'd use `for key,value in switcher.items():` or `switcher.values()` respectively.